# How to limit the number of items in an array column in parse

Tags: arrays, parse-platform

I have an array column in my Parse server. It collects other users who the current user 'follows'. I would like to limit the number of items in this array column, how might that be done? I would like to limit the number of items to 2. 
Here is a screenshot of my Parse server page depicting the username, password and follower columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC8ZN.jpg)

Here is the section of my code that adds a user to the array column "isFollowing"

```
 final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view;
                if (checkedTextView.isChecked()){
                    Log.i("Info", "Checked");

                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().add("isFollowing",users.get(i));
```

This section of my code searches the array adapter 'users' to confirm the users are valid as entered from the editText 'spouseEmailEditText'

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        query.whereEqualTo("username", spouseEmailEditText.getText().toString());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null && objects.size() > 0) {

                    for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                        users.add(user.getUsername());
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Toast.makeText(SpouseConnect.this, "Please Click The Checkmark Next To Your Spouse's Name (if not already checked)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    for (String username: users){
                        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").contains(username)){

                            listView.setItemChecked(users.indexOf(username), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforeSave hook in Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, async (req) => {
  let userObj = req.object;
  let following: [] = userObj.get('isFollowing');
  if (following.length > 2) {
    //Deny to save
    throw 'You can follow up to 2 people';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Suat Karabacak, I will give this a try!

Comment: However, my app is still in development, can I use cloud code in this case?

Comment: Yes you can use cloud code in any time of development.